# How to get year with fractional part from date in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, date-formatting, oracle12c

I need a PL/SQL function that takes a date and returns the year as a number, including a fractional part from the days. For example, `1995-01-01` would be `1995.000` and `2015-11-24` would be `2015.897`. This is what I managed to produce:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION year_fraction (in_date DATE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  year NUMBER;
  days NUMBER;
  total_days NUMBER;
BEGIN
  year := EXTRACT(YEAR FROM in_date);
  days := in_date - TRUNC(in_date, 'YEAR');
  total_days := ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(in_date, 'YEAR'), 12) - TRUNC(in_date, 'YEAR');
  RETURN year + days / total_days;
END year_fraction;
```

It works, but it feels like to much work to solve quite a simple problem. Can this be done in a neater way?

Comment: you can get the day of the year with `to_number(to_char(in_date, 'ddd'))`

Comment: You can get the day as a number with `extract(day from in_date)`, but I think that's about as simple as it could get while still being clear about the steps involved.

Comment: @DavidAldridge That gives me the day of the month, not the day of the year.

Comment: Oh so it does. Well I think you're good then -- go with what you've got. If you're concerned about performance then investigate function result caching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I ended up using this solution. It is quite similar to what I started out with in the question, but involves fewer function calls and is a bit more condensed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fractional_year (in_date DATE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  year DATE;
BEGIN
  year := TRUNC(in_date, 'YEAR');
  -- Year + Days passed so far / Total number of days in year
  RETURN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM year) + (in_date - year) / (ADD_MONTHS(year, 12) - year);
END fractional_year;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want the decimal part as percentage of days passed in current year. It would be a simple **date arithmetic to divide the day of the year with total days in that year**.

```
SQL> SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
  2    ||'.'
  3    ||TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DDD'))/
  4    (add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'year'), 12) - TRUNC(SYSDATE,'year'))*1000) my_format
  5  FROM DUAL;

MY_FORMAT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2015.898
```

Comment: @Anders Ok, see the updated answer. To be precise, it woul dbe `89.8%` not `89.7`. Please mark it as answered, would help others too!

Comment: My goal here is not to get rid of the PL/SQL, but to do the conversion in a cleaner more readable way. To me this looks very much like the solution I already proposed in my question, but using string concatenation instead of number addition to combine the integer and fraction parts.

Comment: I think the neater and better way was to do it in one step in pure SQL. Which is there in the answer,